# Angular Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" in REST-call

Tags: angular, rest, http

I need to set header "Cookie" in my REST-call to server, but get Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" in my browser.
Can anyone please help me with how to get around this problem in Angular.

```
  public getData(): Observable<any> {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Cookie', 'access_token=eyJh...');

    return this.http.get<any>(`/v1/getData`, {
      headers: httpHeaders,
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }
```